# I cannot install scrapy in my computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, installation

i use python 3.4.2,under the environment win10.And i have installed scrapy successfully.But when i test it in cmd window ,it raise exception[image]

anyone knows about it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the traceback as text instead of images and google before you post

Answer (score 0):

use `pip install <package name>`

Comment: i have figure out this problem ,i need to install cryptography.'pip install cryptography'

Comment: @martin yes, this's what I mean.